# What would be better to do(Pass in the object into the service or the username into the service?)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, repository

what would be better to do

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    User user = accountService.GetUser(User.Identity)
    Product project = productService.GetSomething(user);
    Store store = storeService.GetSomething(user);
}

 Or

public ActionResult Test()
{
    Product project = productService.GetSomething(User.Identity);
    Store store = storeService.GetSomething(User.Identity);
}
```

In the first one I have a service layer that takes in the userName and calls up a repo to get the user record back. Then I pass it along and use it in other service layers.

Now in option 2 I pass in the username and in that service layer I call the same repo the accountService would call.

Only difference is I am passing in a string vs and object.

I see both have up sides and downsides. If your just having one method that needs the users data then it kinda sucks to have to call another service layer to get it and pass it into another one.

If you have multiple ones it might potentially save some queries to the database(however I nhibernate might just cache it anyways)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Law of Demeter : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

Or even better, look at this part of the excellent Clean Code Talk from Google: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=RlfLCWKxHJ0#t=944s 
There, Law of demeters gets epxlained very well. Or just view the whole video, they are all good btw.

In short, passing the smallest possible component makes the code more readable, more expressive, more testable. The "bigger" the object, the more it hides the intention of the method/constructor using it. And the harder/more complicated it is to create a stub/mock later on, especially because your own classes tend to "grow" over time. If you don't have to create stubs at all (as you use e.g. value types like in your case instead of reference types) it's the best you can achieve.

Comment: hmm. I see what you mean. My next question would be what would be better. option 1 but instead of passing in the whole user object instead just pass in the User.Id. The problem I see with this is though now I have to have a null check to see if a user existed in my controller instead of where it is right now(a service layer check).

Comment: Good comments on clean code, but there are times when you will want to use a class instance (or struct instance) instead of primitives. Generally, if you have a method like, void DoSomething(string, string, string) then it can get confusing as to which string goes where, and an error in the order can cause logical failures that are hard to resolve. Better to pass an object that contains the relevant information like void DoWork(UserClass). I know my names are very ambiguous - so a more concrete exacmple might be public bool SaveUser(UserInfo info)

Comment: You should try to avoid passing null at all, so you can save if checks, if you/the team sticks to the rule. One other clean code rule.. but of course you need a substitute, in this case this would be an exception, as this (again) is rather expressive. Of course, this should be a really "exceptional" case, but not finding a single user by passed Id is such a case, imho. UserNotFounException in the log deep down a stacktrace is more expressive than "nullreference exception". That would really suck in the long run. The exception is part of the definition, easy to see.

Comment: As for the string/string/string signature example: in many casses this is a code smell of someone not using enough enums. I cannot stress enough how usefull they are to understand legacy/old code: and all code becomes old code eventually. :/ There are of course cases where that makes sense, as long as these domain transfer objects (or whatever you call them) don't contain logic, and only have few simple types in them. Or at least as simple as possible. Very good point, and thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @chobo2 just to enhance the comment on "what to do instead of returning null": there is also the NullObject pattern, look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Generally the less heavy, the better. While your object may only have three fields, that still means a lot more data, per object, being sent to the web service.

Usually, you want to send the tiniest bit of unique identifier that you can get away with. If possible, I would send the UserID assuming it's a numeric data item, and have your service get all the other info it needs from the backend.

Comment: That makes sense. However, right now the the service layer and repo are in one project file and the mvc stuff is another file. So there is no service call. It's the mvc stuff references the .dll. So I don't see this problem occuring.

Comment: Oh, yea, if you're passing around stuff "in memory," then it makes no difference because you are really just passing a reference to an object (not the while object). The only time where this isn't the case is if the object is a struct (structs are copied into methods, not passed by reference).